# getBoundingClientRect().width not returning correct width

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I am trying to get the width of an element, but the value is always less than the actual width. This is my code so far:

```
this.rightSectionElement = this.$('.sections').eq(1).get(0);
this.rightSectionOffset = this.rightSectionElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Where the CSS on the element in question is this:

```
nav{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include inline-flex();
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;

    .sections{
              @include flex-value(0 1 auto);
              height: 100%;
              width: auto;
              display: block;
...
```

Does this method not play very well with elements arranged by flexbox?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was going on? When I use getBoundingClientRect() with flexbox I lose 40px in the width and 5px in the height.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any margin or borders applied to the element? getBoundClientRect() does not take into account margin or borders when calculating the width.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/aprax/t94cj9hh/1/

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 5px;
}
--------------
//Outputs 300
document.write(document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect().width);
```